# Defining McEliece parameter tuple (n, k, t) with BouncyCastle's tuple (m, t, poly)

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric, key-generator

I am using BouncyCastles Java API and want to use McEliece encryption. After browsing through various paper for finding good parameters (e.g. [How to choose McEliece's parameters?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26718/how-to-choose-mcelieces-parameters)) I am now having the problem, that I do not see a possibility to set these parameters with the BouncyCastle API.

In all papers, the parameter set is a 3-tuple: *(n, k, t)*. But with BouncyCastle, I can only specify the 3-tuple *(m, t, poly)* for keypair generation with:

```
new McElieceCCA2Parameters(m, t, poly)
```

**How do they correspond to the *(n, k, t)* parameter set?**

Comment: Not sure which bouncycastle version you're referring to, but [in 1.52 `McElieceCCA2Parameters`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.52/org/bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/mceliece/McElieceCCA2Parameters.java#McElieceCCA2Parameters) takes at most, `m` and `t`.

Comment: I am using version 1.55 ;-) But nevertheless, when there were only 2 parameters back in 1.52, how could one specify them, so that one get a setting of e.g. *(n, k, t)* = *(6624,5129,118)* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `m`, `t` and `poly` define a Goppa code.`m` represents a degree of a polynomial over GF2 that generates support within the code. `n` represents number of elements in the support/length of encrypted message in bits. I had a quick look at [McElieceParameters](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.52/org/bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/mceliece/McElieceParameters.java#McElieceParameters) and they use full support. It means that `n` is always equal to `2^m`. `t`, number of errors that the code can correct, must be chosen from interval `[2; (n - 1)/m]` and `k` is implicitly equal to `n - m*t`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did not understand it completely. Is `t` in both tuple the same? And when I solve `k=n-m*t` for m with *(n, k, t)* being *(6624,5129,118)*, I get `m≈12.67`. But `m` has to be an integer.
Could you maybe just provide a simple example? E.g. how I have to specify `(m, t, poly)` to get `(n, k, t)` = *(6624,5129,118)*?

Comment: As far as I can see, BouncyCastle calculates `n=1<<m`, so there is no possibility to get `n` to be anything else than the values of power of 2. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ph3n1x sorry for incomplete answer. Yes, `t` is the same in both `(n, k, t)` and `(m, t, poly)` notations. You are right, n is always power of 2. From what I have seen the bouncy castle library does not allow your required setup.